# App life cycle in Xamarin.Forms: What happens to active threads?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, lifecycle

still new to App development it would be great if you could clarify some points for me. I know that when my App is about to loose focus certain Methods in my App class are called that I can override to react on this events. But what is not clear to me is what happens to active threads in my App?

1. What happens to the active thread of my App when the App looses focus?
2. What if it is in an event handler at this moment?
3. What happens with `async` functions?
4. What happens to background threads that I have created with `Task.Start`?

In which state is the App when it regains focus, meaning not being restarted?